I don't know how to make my code work correctly
I was practicing and I tried defining mathematical functions and other stuff, but then I got a bunch of errors and I ended up not having an error but the result was wrong. This is the code as of writing this:
def factorial(num):
 n = 1
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        n *= i
    return n

def series(start, end, expression):
    m = 0
    for n in range(start, end+1):
        m+=eval(expression)
    return m

ans1 = input("Do you want to use factorial or a series? ")
if ans1 == "Yes":
     ans2 = input("Series or factorial? ")
     if ans2 == "Series":
        start = int(input("Select the starting value of n. "))
        end = int(input("Select the final value of n. "))
        expression = input("Type the expression to be run in terms of n. ")
        m = series(start, end, expression)
        print("The result is: " + str(m))
     if ans2 == "Factorial":
        factorizing = int(input("Select the number to factorize. "))
        n = factorial(factorizing)
        print(n)
elif ans1 == "No":
     print("Ok!")

Thanks for the help, the factorial() is working perfectly now, but when in series i tried series(1, 5, 2*n+1), it gave me 35 when it was supposes to give 25, anyone know whats wrong?

your first line of code in the snippet is wrong. youre missing def factorial(num):

Please read [ask].

n and m only exist as local variables to the functions.  Assign the return value of the function called, e.g. n = factorial(factorizing) and m = series(start, end, expression).

Your indentation is wrong, you should fix it before anything else.

"I don't know how to make my code work correctly" could be the title of half the questions on Stack Overflow.  Your question title should summarize what is specific to your question.  You also need to edit your body to include full details about what is going wrong.  What are all the inputs you are using that produce bad outputs? What are those outputs?  Are you getting any error messages?  "got a bunch of errors" is not enough to help you debug.

You need to fix the logic. Such as start and end:
def factorial(num):
    n = 1
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        n *= i
    return n


def series(start, end, expression):
    m = 0
    for n in range(start, end + 1):
        m += eval(expression)
    return m

ans1 = input("Do you want to use factorial or a series? Type `Yes` or `No`. ")
if ans1.lower() == "yes":
    ans2 = input("Series or factorial? ")
    if ans2.lower() == "series":
        start_end = input("Type start and end values, like `3 4`: ")
        start, end = start_end.split()
        start, end = int(start), int(end)
        if start > end:
            start, end = end, start
        expression = input("Type the expression to be run in terms of n: ")
        result = series(start, end, expression)
        print("The result is: " + str(result))
    elif ans2.lower() == "factorial":
        factorizing = int(input("Select the number to factorize: "))
        result = factorial(factorizing)
        print("The result is: " + str(result))
elif ans1.lower() == "no":
    print("Ok!")


Prints
Do you want to use factorial or a series? Type `Yes` or `No`. yes
Series or factorial? series
Type start and end values, like `3 4`: 10 5
Type the expression to be run in terms of n: 4
The result is: 24

For Factorial:
Do you want to use factorial or a series? Type `Yes` or `No`. yes
Series or factorial? factorial
Select the number to factorize: 5
The result is: 120


Make sure your equations are correct.
You can add details instructions so that all errors would be handled.


The variables n and m are not defined in the scope where you are trying to access it. Your functions are returning a number, but you are never assigning the value to a variable. It is an easy fix:
if ans2 == "Series":
        start = int(input("Select the starting value of n. "))
        end = int(input("Select the final value of n. "))
        expression = input("Type the expression to be run in terms of n. ")
        m = series(start, end, expression)
        print("The result is: " + str(m))
 if ans2 == "Factorial":
        factorizing = int(input("Select the number to factorize. "))
        n = factorial(factorizing)
        print(n)

